# Async parallel and promises wont work

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have the following two snippets:

1.this is the unit I would like to run:

```
health.checkHealth = function (req, res) {
async.parallel({
    cassandra: function (callback) {
        cassandraRepository.ping(callback);
    },
    kafka: function (callback) {
        kafkaHelper.ping(callback);
    },
    vault: function (callback) {
        vaultClient.health()
            .then((isOk)=>{
                 callback(null, isOk)})
            .catch(()=>
                callback(null, false));
    }
}, function (err, result) {
    var response = {};
    if (result.cassandra) {
        response.cassandra = "OK";
    } else {
        response.cassandra = "Failed";
        res.status(500);
    }

    if (result.kafka) {
        response.kafka = "OK";
    } else {
        response.kafka = "Failed";
        res.status(500);
    }

    if (result.vault) {
        response.vault = "OK";
    } else {
        response.vault = "Failed";
        res.status(500);
    }

    res.send(response);
})
```

}

2.this is the test to check the unit:

```
     describe('vault is avaliable', function () {
        beforeEach(sinon.test(function () {
            sinon.stub(vaultClient, "health").resolves(true);
        }));

        it('should return 200', sinon.test(function (done) {
            var response = {
                vault: "OK"
            };

            var req = {};
            var res = {};
            var spySend = res.send = sinon.spy();
            var spyStatus = res.status = sinon.spy();

            health.checkHealth(req, res);
            expect(spySend.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
            expect(spySend.calledWith(response));
            expect(spyStatus.calledOnce).to.equal(false);
        }));

    });
```

My problem is that when I call checkHealth it proceeds to the next line (expect(spySend.calledOnce).to.equal(true);) without waiting for the vaultClient's promise to complete.
 What do I need to do to make the expects run only after the 'checkHealth' was run.

Comment: Yes. Don't use `async.js` with promises.

Comment: What promise library are you using?

Comment: @Bergi its native promise. there is no way to overcome this using promise?

Comment: Yes. Just drop `async.parallel` and use `Promise.all` instead. You might want to [promisify](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) `ping` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use the `async` - you can use promises directly in your code with `Promise.all` as others have suggested.

The code here is using `promisifyAll` from Bluebird, but you can also [convert the APIs to use promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) yourself.

```
//.props is bluebird, you can `.all` with native promises too
Promise.props({
    cassandra: cassandraRepository.pingAsync(); // created by promisifyAll
    kafka: kafkaHelper.pingAsync(),
    vault: vaultClient.health()
}).then(results => {
   // access results.cassandra, results.kafka and results.vaule here
});
```